# SQL query is causing problem while inserting into table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-update, pymysql

I tried to insert dataframe using pymysql library. 
It's giving this error:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''bestwebsites'
>   ('Rank','Score','Category','Audience','URL','Links','Desc') VALUE' at
>   line 1")

```
import pandas as pd 
import re
# import sqlalchemy
import pymysql


df = pd.read_csv('final_data.csv')
df = df.drop(['blank','Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)
df['Desc']
df['Desc'] = df['Desc'].str.replace("[-',’]",'').astype(str)
df.columns

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='root',
                             db='pythondb')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cols = "','".join([str(i) for i in df.columns.tolist()])

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    sql = "INSERT INTO 'bestwebsites' ('" +cols+ "') VALUES (" + "%s,"*(len(row)-1) + "%s)"
    cursor.execute(sql,list(row))

    connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I tried using sqlalchemy It's working

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/pythondb')

df.to_sql(name='bestwebsites',
        con=engine,
        index=False,
        if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names (and table names) should not be surrounded with single quotes. You can use unqote them if they conform to MySQL rules for unquoted identifiers, or use backticks for quoting:

```
cols = "`,`".join([str(i) for i in df.columns.tolist()])

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    sql = "INSERT INTO `bestwebsites` (`" +cols+ "`) VALUES (" + "%s,"*(len(row)-1) + "%s)"
    cursor.execute(sql,list(row))   

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Side note: it is more efficient to perform all `insert`s first, and then commit - rather than committing after each and every insert.

Comment: Thankyou, You solved the problem and thankyou for some extra information.